# Howto disassemble regex objects to compare performance

Tags: python, regex

Given the following string

```
1234

1234
```

We can use [`re.search(r'^\d{4}\Z')`](https://regex101.com/r/vBS4ip/1) to find only the last four numbers or [`re.search(r'^\d{4}(?!\[\r\n\])')`](https://regex101.com/r/vBS4ip/2). How do I get a bytecode analysis (maybe with the `dis` module?) to compare which one is more effective? I know I could use `timeit` but am really interested in the internals.

Comment: if you are interested in the internals of regex (as opposed to python itself), you might want to try the regex debugger feature of regex101.com (which shows you step by step how the regex is evaluated)

Comment: @Lukor: I know but am really interested how `\Z` is translated in bytecode.

Comment: In Python, debugging a regex pattern is done using `re.DEBUG` flag, `re.search(r'^\d{4}\Z', s, re.DEBUG)`. However, `\Z` and `$(?!(?s:.))` are really very close in performance. Just `\Z` is the solution in case you do not want to match before the final newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is, I close it myself as a duplicate.